# How do i analyze my data statistically

Tags: hypothesis-testing, excel

I need help regarding hypothesis testing. Not a statistics major but familiar with basic concepts (basic descriptive statistics, frequency, measures of: central tendency, location, dispersion) so please forgive and correct my technical mistakes. So i have a research on the relationship/s of intelligence and religiosity among students (Male and Female). i was advised (by my adviser, who btw is not a statistics major) to use hypothesis testing but i have no idea how to conduct it. i will link the excel file to my google drive. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hb717PcbdQ0t2MWz9MDdnPH_Bvq-obcs

Comment: You are going to have to explain something about your variables and what your working hypotheses are. What do you need to know?

Comment: here are the questions:

-Determine religiosity/atheism and intelligence among male and female students

-Determine the correlation between the two variables for both sexes.

variables:

-religiosity - basically how religious the respondents are (1 for strongly disagree, 5 for strongly agree)

-atheism- lack of religiosity

-intelligence - cognitive ability of the respondents (measured using IQ test; exam scores will have their corresponding IQs)

i used non-probabilistic sampling (quota sampling) for determining my sample

Comment: If you want hypothesis tests you're going to need some actual hypotheses. The best time to pin those down is before you collect data (and similarly with questions of suitable sample sizes, since they are connected to the hypotheses and the expected effect size). Please put any relevant information into the question, since comments are ephemeral (they can disappear at any time).

Comment: A lot of your variables seem only to have 5 as value for all individuals - so if the data displayed in the link is the complete dataset - then this implies you are gonna run into the problem of perfect multicollinearity.

Comment: @Eugene for you question to be reopened - so that people might try to help you further - you'll need to edit your original post to clarify it. Start by putting the information you placed in comments into the body of the post. Note that the person that posted an answer asked several questions; you'll need to answer those (perhaps initially in a comment under their answer so they see you responded - but then copy all relevant information into your question).

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a pretty good start, here's my advice.

1) Your null hypotheses could use additional clarity (but kudos for stating them in the first place).  Specifically in your first null hypothesis: "there is no difference in religiosity, intelligence, and atheism of M/F students...", what 'difference' are you looking for? In the language of experimental design, what are your independent/dependent variables?

With respect to your second null hypothesis "...between...students in general": what does this mean, exactly?  How do you propose to test for a difference between *all students in general?*  Who will you compare the "students in general" to?

Properly phrasing your study goals in the form of a hypothesis is a great, but largely informal, way to help you visualize the goals of your study and how your data will be used.

Operating under the assumption that you are interested in looking at differences in intelligence between students while controlling for religious attitudes and gender, you have a couple strategies available.  Since I don't know what resources are available to you in terms of software, I'll simply pitch the strategy I recommend: fitting a linear model to the data.  This *can* be done in Excel but I don't recommend it as it is prone to error.  Instead, I suggest you import your data into software designed for statistical analysis (such as R, which is free to download and use).

[This resource](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/two-way-anova-using-spss-statistics.php) explains a bit about the idea behind fitting a model like yours, and how it would work in SPSS (another common statistical software application).  Unfortunately, there is a lot you will have to consider (e.g., checking assumptions of a model, understanding the output, etc.) that I think are outside the scope of this question.